# Trainings Time of Original ResNet?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am looking for Information on the original ResNet. I would be curious how long training roughly took. I know that a current challenge is to train the model as quickly as possible, but I really just care about how long it took back in 2015?

I also could not find it in the original paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a blog-post (http://torch.ch/blog/2016/02/04/resnets.html) linked from the original github, 0.4s / batch of 32 images is recorded for ResNet-50, and it's written that "training took from 3.5 days for the 18-layer model to 14 days for the 101-layer model". Also note that this is an optimized implementation compared to the original work from the authors, and uses 4 gpus, whereas the original work isn't clear about the parallelism used on ImageNet training.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is probably the closest (to the original )thing I have come across so far.